# Enable Command Not Found messages in Other Shells (like Zsh)

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I found out how to allow the "`... command not found but can be installed with...`" to appear in Oh-my-zsh by adding `source /etc/zsh_command_not_found` to my `.zshrc`.

But now, when I type a command that doesn't exist but there isn't a "...can be installed with" message, there is no output, acting as if I entered a command that had no output.

Original (Expected) Behavior:

```
~$ Non_existant_command
Non_existant_command: command not found
~$
```

New (Unwanted) Behavior:

```
~$ Non_existant_command
~$
```

Overall, I want the "command not found, but can be installed with" messages that are in bash to appear in zsh (or whatever shell I'm using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be because `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` invokes `/usr/lib/command-not-found` with the `--no-failure-msg` option:

```
 % cat /etc/zsh_command_not_found
# (c) Zygmunt Krynicki 2007,
# Licensed under GPL, see COPYING for the whole text
#
# This script will look-up command in the database and suggest
# installation of packages available from the repository

if [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] ; then
        if (( ! ${+functions[command_not_found_handler]} )) ; then
                function command_not_found_handler {
                        [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] || return 1
                        /usr/lib/command-not-found --no-failure-msg -- ${1+"$1"} && :
                }
        fi
fi
```

where

```
 % /usr/lib/command-not-found --help
Usage: command-not-found [options] <command-name>

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DATA_DIR, --data-dir=DATA_DIR
                        use this path to locate data fields
  --ignore-installed, --ignore-installed
                        ignore local binaries and display the available
                        packages
  --no-failure-msg      don't print '<command-name>: command not found'
```

If you want the message to show, you can make a local copy of the `zsh_command_not_found` script, edit it to remove that option, and source *that* instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. At first it was not working, but I got it to work quickly.